# How do I tell if Jenkins checkout pulled anything?

Tags: jenkins

I have a pipleline build that traverses other repos to check for updates. I have this in my jenkins pipeline script:  (as part of a loop that goes through other repos)

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@gitlab.me.com:me/myRepo.git',credentialsId:'my-key']]
])
```

Is there a way in the code to tell if there were any updates?  When I normally do a "git pull" I get a message saying "Already up to date."

Basically,  if there is no change in the repo, I don't want to continue with the script.  How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checkout` should return a map of values set by the git plugin.  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

So I believe you could do this:

```
def map = checkout ...
if (map.GIT_COMMIT == map.GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT) {
  // no changes
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But this script actually traverses other repos, so I need to know if a different repo has been updated.  (I updated my question, sorry I was not clear)